# Linux CRC Error

Tags: ubuntu, motherboard

I'm getting an error when trying to boot from live Ubuntu cd. "Uncompressing Linux... crc error -- System halted". I've also tried this using a Linux mint live cd, same error. Is this something related to the MB?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.articlealley.com/article_941641_11.html) the kernel doesn't like itself. Based on what you've said, I feel like your hard drive might be to blame. Is it old? Do you have a spare to test on?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try the live cd on another computer, or a different cd rom in the same computer.

If you can't do either of those, I'd try [installing from a flash drive.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

I think that a flakey cd drive is more likely than the motherboard. You can also try a memory test, live cd [here](http://www.sysresccd.org/) or some Ubuntu live cds have it on there.

Motherboard problems could in theory be an issue too, but I've never seen it, so I'd try the above first.